# How do I create multiple charts at the same page with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, charts, chart.js

I already had created a chart just for example with chart.js. But the chart needs to be with dinamic data. 
I have an object with my data. And i need to create one chart for each index. 
My object is like:

```
var example = [ [project{ data:['24/12/1994','25/12/1994'] qtd: [1,5]},
project{ data:['24/12/1994','25/12/1994'] qtd: [1,5]} ];
```

So for each project I need a chart, and could have more projects everytime so it needs to be dinamic. But I just know to put data at the chart with $scope So how do I do this? Any idea?

I really appreciate the help.

This is my HTML if that helps:

```
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">
    </canvas> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I believe your data will be like this,

```
var example = [{
                  project: {data:['24/12/1994','25/12/1994'], qtd: [1,5]
               },{
                  project: {data:['24/12/1994','25/12/1994'], qtd: [1,5]
               }];
```

The object format you have posted in question is wrong.

To do this, firstly you need to save the whole data in a $scope like

```
$scope.chartData = example; //example is what we defined above or your response
```

the in html you have to ngRepeat the canvas for displaying each chart.

```
  <div class="chart-container">
    <canvas 
            ng-repeat="data in chartData"
            chart-data="{{data}}"
            id="line" class="chart chart-line"
            chart-labels="labels"
            chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
            chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"
            chart-click="onClick">
    </canvas> 
  </div>
```

Here I passed `data` in `chart-data="{{data}}"` guessing you need to pass the each object in your array of objects.

If you want to pass only project object in each object, then
`chart-data="{{data.project}}"`

and `chart-data="{{data.qtd}}"` in case of qtd object